# Why should the 13th Warrior not be a Northman?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-13th-warrior

[The 13th Warrior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_13th_Warrior) should not be a Northman. So they recruit an Arab, Ahmed Ibn to be the 13th Warrior.

Why should the 13th Warrior not be a Northman?

Comment: Because...the prophecy said so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because there was a prediction that they would fail if they didn't include someone not from the North.

[**IMDB Synopsis**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120657/synopsis?ref_=tt_stry_pl)

> Regardless of his feelings towards them, an old soothsayer whom the Vikings call the angel of death, cast the bones and **warns the band that they will fail unless they are accompanied on their journey by a 13th warrior and one who is not from the North.**

The soothsayer has, essentially, *they believe*, seen the future and can tell them that he will play an essential part in their struggle.

Comment: I'm confused whether it is Norseman or Northman?

Comment: @AJ Essentially interchangable - http://www.differencebetween.net/miscellaneous/culture-miscellaneous/difference-between-norse-and-viking/

Answer (score -1):

Mostly because 13 is a unlucky number in Europe and in Norse mythology. Loki a 13th god killed Balder and was 13th guest at funeral. But because Nords are very proud they don't consider arab a "person" so the thirteen member would not be unlucky if he won't be one of them.